# Unescaping filenames generated by ls -R

Tags: python, shell, escaping, ls

I have a text file containing the output of a recursive directory listing that generally looks like this:

```
./subfolder/something with spaces:
something\ with\ spaces.txt*
something\ with\ spaces.dat*

./subfolder/yet another thing:
yet\ another\ thing.txt*
yet\ another\ thing.dat*
```

I need to get a list of the full paths to each .txt file:

```
./subfolder/something with spaces/something with spaces.txt
./subfolder/yet another thing/yet another thing.txt
```

I've almost got a solution for this, but what's the best solution for unescaping the filenames in Python? I don't know exactly what characters `ls -R` escaped (space and = are two such characters, though). I don't have access to the drive containing these files, either, so using a better command to obtain the list is out of the question, unfortunately.

Comment: Surely you would do better not processing the output of `ls -R` but have Python generate the list of file names directly.  There must be modules to do this - but I'm a Perl user rather than Python, so I can't tell you what they're called.  Google search with the terms 'python directory search' provides lots of useful looking places to start.

Comment: @Jonathan the OP already mentioned he has no access to the drive, so things like `walk` are not helpful here.

Comment: Missed that...oh well...life is hell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if there's built-in for this, but a simple regex could be used.

```
re.sub(r'(?<!\\)\\', '', filename)
```

This would remove all backslashes (except for those following another backslash). This seems to be the behavior when you try and `echo` these values on the terminal (I've only tested this in bash).

```
bash-3.2$ echo foo\\bar
foo\bar
bash-3.2$ echo foo\ bar
foo bar
bash-3.2$ echo foo\=bar
foo=bar
```

Here's a complete python example:

```
import re

def unescape(filename):
    return re.sub(r'(?<!\\)\\', '', filename)

print unescape(r'foo\ bar')
print unescape(r'foo\=bar')
print unescape(r'foo\\bar')
```

Output:

```
foo bar
foo=bar
foo\bar
```